# Variable "name" is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final

Tags: java

So the title says it all. I'm getting a compilation error inside of my JsonObjectRequest

I'm sure this is a really simple fix, but I'm not exactly sure how to write it. I'm still in the early stages of android development, so pardon my noob-ness. :)

Here's the code.

```
public class Api {

public static final String SEARCH_URL = "http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/account/list/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31&search=";
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private ArrayList<String> mNames;

public Api(Context context) {
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
}

public ArrayList<String> searchPlayer(String name) {


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, SEARCH_URL + name, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject json) {

            try {
                JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                    String n = name.getString("nickname");
                    mNames.add(n);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    }
    );

    mQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return mNames;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `final` to the argument declaration:

```
public ArrayList<String> searchPlayer(final String name)
```

Comment: after replacement, IDE curse: error: cannot find symbol method getString(String)

Comment: `String n = name.getString("nickname");` isn't valid. It tells you the line number of the problem so you can find it, and the error itself tells you what is wrong. The class `String` does not have a method `getString(String)`. The comment on the other answer is probably correct in that you intended `String n = c.getString("nickname");`.

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, replace

```
public ArrayList<String> searchPlayer(String name)
```

with

```
public ArrayList<String> searchPlayer(final String name)
```

The argument must be declared `final` to ensure that it never gets changed by the code inside the method, and thus can be safely used inside the response listener.

Comment: after replacement, IDE curse: error: cannot find symbol method getString(String)

Comment: @user2858339, that's a different issue. If `name` is a string, what exactly do you expect to obtain by using `name.getString("nickname");`? Or do you mean `c.getString("nickname")`?